# How to fix StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, encryption, indexoutofboundsexception, caesar-cipher

I have been trying to get this code to work, but I keep getting the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. Can anyone help me find a fix to that problem? I have been trying to mess around with the index. The first while loop works fine alone, but when I put the second one in it goes bananas.

```
public static String encrypt(int key, String name) {
        String encryptedName = "";
        int i = 0;

        while((int) name.charAt(i) > 64 && (int) name.charAt(i) < 91) {
            if((int)name.charAt(i) + key > 90 ) {
                encryptedName += (char) ((int) name.charAt(i) + key - 26); 
            } else {
                encryptedName += (char) ((int) name.charAt(i) + key);
            }

            i++;
        }

        i = 0;  

        while((int) name.charAt(i) > 96 && (int) name.charAt(i+1) < 123 && i < name.length() - 1) {
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
            if((int)name.charAt(i) + key > 122) {
                encryptedName += (char) ((int) name.charAt(i) + key - 26);
            } else {
                encryptedName += (char) ((int) name.charAt(i) + key);
            }
        }

        return encryptedName;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of   range: 7
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Cipher.encrypt(Cipher.java:61)
    at Cipher.main(Cipher.java:26)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, and include the inputs for which the code fails

Comment: The point of the code is to take the frist name, middle name ,last name and a key from the user. it would then print out the encrypted name by using the key to go up the alphabet. uppercase characters need to stay upper case and lower case stay lower. And you cant go out of the alphabet or get any numbers. For key i"d use 12 and for name i would use Raymond.
So if the name started with Z and the key was 1 you'd get A as the first letter and so on and so forth.

Comment: Which string is throwing the index error?  The input plaintext, the key or the cyphertext?  From that you have given us we cannot determine what line 61 contains.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a condition to break out of the loop before i gets too big.

E.g.

```
while (i < name.length() && ...)
```

and for the second loop, add

```
while (i + 1 < name.length && ...)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. For key=12 and name =Raymond, it says string index out of range: 7. Also i put a println(i) statement inside the loop to see when the error would appear and its after i = 5.

Comment: The order matters.  The i + 1 < name.length() must be the first condition.

Comment: If this answered your original question, please accept this answer and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In the second while loop, try to move i++  to the bottom of your while loop.